# How to watch and use addresses generated from xpub

Tags: bitcore

**How to watch the addresses generated using xpub for incoming transactions? and Create transactions to send bitcoin to another address.**

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');
var Address = bitcore.Address;
var PublicKey = bitcore.PublicKey;
var Networks = bitcore.Networks;

var xpub = 'tpubDFaw2mL2nZuxk9WeCTr5Y74xytQLqtxSet3FYigfTMX788gjZmd4juFYeLDchGMaXmjGeoy6FrULbZd9D8iogcPZyBeYfT5MAyqnaL8bMQb';
var hdPublickey = new bitcore.HDPublicKey(xpub);
var orderPublickey = hdPublickey.derive("m/44/0/4/0/0");
var pubkey = new PublicKey(orderPublickey.publicKey);
var address = Address.fromPublicKey(pubkey, Networks.mainnet);

console.log(address.toString());
```

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I using bitpay to get the xpub and doing programming in nodejs

Comment: my requirement is how to watch this newly generated address for incoming transactions  and transfer the bitcoin from this address to another address if funds come

Comment: If you're into nodejs you should check out bcoin. It's a library, full node, and wallet. You can create a watch-only wallet and import an xpub. https://bcoin.io